# Python 3: Last Row of Database only viewing in tkinter table

Tags: postgresql, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to display the database table in tkinter, but i am only getting last row in the tableview. how can i get entire rows in my tkinter.

Spec:

Python3,
Postgresql,
psycopg2,
tkinnter

Thanks in advance

```
class MultiColumnListbox(object):
"""use a ttk.TreeView as a multicolumn ListBox"""

def __init__(self):
    self.tree = None
    self._setup_widgets()
    self._build_tree()

def _setup_widgets(self):
    s = """WOW CALL LIST"""
    msg = ttk.Label(wraplength="4i", justify="left", anchor="n",
        padding=(10, 2, 10, 6), text=s)
    msg.pack(fill='x')
    container = ttk.Frame()
    container.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
    # create a treeview with dual scrollbars
    self.tree = ttk.Treeview(columns=car_header, show="headings")
    vsb = ttk.Scrollbar(orient="vertical",
        command=self.tree.yview)
    hsb = ttk.Scrollbar(orient="horizontal",
        command=self.tree.xview)
    self.tree.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set,
        xscrollcommand=hsb.set)
    self.tree.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='nsew', in_=container)
    vsb.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky='ns', in_=container)
    hsb.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky='ew', in_=container)
    container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)



 def _build_tree(self):



        for col in car_header:
            self.tree.heading(col, text=col.title(),
                command=lambda c=col: sortby(self.tree, c, 0))
            # adsjust the column's width to the header string
            self.tree.column(col,
                width=tkFont.Font().measure(col.title()))

        for item in car_list:
            self.tree.insert('', 'end', values=item)
            # adjust column's width if necessary to fit each value
            for ix, val in enumerate(item):
                col_w = tkFont.Font().measure(val)
                if self.tree.column(car_header[ix],width=None)<col_w:
                    self.tree.column(car_header[ix], width=col_w)

def sortby(tree, col, descending):
    """sort tree contents when a column header is clicked on"""
    # grab values to sort
    data = [(tree.set(child, col), child) \
        for child in tree.get_children('')]
    # if the data to be sorted is numeric change to float
    #data =  change_numeric(data)
    # now sort the data in place
    data.sort(reverse=descending)
    for ix, item in enumerate(data):
        tree.move(item[1], '', ix)
    # switch the heading so it will sort in the opposite direction
    tree.heading(col, command=lambda col=col: sortby(tree, col, \
        int(not descending)))

# the test data ...

con = psycopg2.connect("dbname='wowcall' user='postgres' password='Admin@123'")   
cur = con.cursor()

cur.execute("SELECT * FROM wowdata")
ver=cur.fetchall()

for row in ver:
    print(row)


car_header = ['WOW ID',' Agent Name','Customer No']
car_list = [row]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("WOW Call")
    listbox = MultiColumnListbox()
    root.mainloop()
```

this is the result i am getting
[tkinter output & Table rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/An2aQ.png)

One more clarification needed... How to refresh the table automatically in specific time interval?

Comment: How to refresh the Table in specific time interval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create `Treeview` using data from `car_list` so print `car_list` and see what you have on this list. Probably not what you expect.

You create `car_list` using `row` but `row` keeps only last row from database.

You need

```
 car_list = ver
```

or even

```
 car_list = cur.fetchall()
```

Comment: car_list = cur.fetchall()